# I want to run a function when ever the form is clicked on taskbar and it opens

Tags: c#, winforms

The issue doing so is i have used tips and tricks here but the seems to run in a loop and wont give the results.

Basically  i run a `BackgroundWorker` to hit a url get result and paste result to some `Labels`.

I have used `Form_Activated`  but it just keeps on running in a loop and wont stop ever reached to the `BackgroundWorker` completed event .

**MAIN CODE BLOCKS:**

On Form_Load I Run the Function and get the results and show:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Show();
        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Thread already running....");
        }
    }

  private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        loadData(); // scrape a URL and paste info to Labels ....
    }
```

This is it, now the user will minimize the application , now whenever he hits the the taskbar icon the form should rerun the same as in Form_Load. I hope that make sense , i have been able to do that using Form_Activate but it keeps going on .

Any suggestion how to get it done ?

Comment: If you want to run code when the form gets opened from the taskbar then perhaps the getfocus event is something you could use?

Comment: @maam27 did not check that one i will give it a try any example code or link

Comment: Have you tried the [Form_Shown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx ) event? It gets fired when the form is fully visible.

Comment: @P.K. nope checking now..it only works the first time form loads..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store a boolean to remember if the form was minimized at the last FormResized event, and then if it was and if the form isn't currently minimized then call your method.

```
private bool minimized = false;

public void FormResized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        minimized = true;
    }

    if (minimized && this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        minimized = false;
        MyMethod();
    }
}
```